# Raw sql with EF Core and in-memory db provider

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

One of my API routes uses a raw sql `merge into` command in order to do an atomic upsert operation, and in my automated tests I've got a `TestServer` instance that uses the in-memory db provider. It gives me an error, probably because the in-memory provider doesn't support running raw sql commands - is that true? If not, how do I get it to work?

Here's the `Startup` class for the tests:

```
// In memory DB for testing
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("stuff"));
services.AddDbContext<MyStatusContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("status"));
services.AddDbContext<MyUserRolesContext>(optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("userroles"));
```

And the API code is as you'd expect:

```
var count = await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(@"merge into ...", default(CancellationToken), ...);
return count;
```

This code works fine in production against a real database, I just can't get it working with the in-memory provider in my tests. Is there any hope for me? What's the usual test strategy for custom sql scripts?

Comment: Also, worth noting that the 3 contexts all point to the same real database, we just have separate contexts in the code for different domains (sets of tables).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no hope for you, as the InMemory provider is a NoSQL non-relational provider. You should use SQL Server (for example localdb) for integration testing

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling, just wanted to be sure. We ended up just covering this with unit tests and validating the actual query manually, it was a sufficient tradeoff for our needs.

Comment: @ErikEJ do you know if this is still the case? I'm trying to do tests of `FromSql` with in-memory db context and ran into this issue.  There samples out there of people who are mocking FromSql and DbQuery/DbSet and I just don't think that's a good way to go.

Comment: Yes, nothing has changed here

Comment: if you run ci/cd on linux then good luck with localdb. not supported. a classic M$ catastrophe. so what do we use?

Comment: SQL Express should fit the bill

Answer (score 5):

As you've discovered the in-memory provider can't do relational operations (a reasonable limitation).

I had similar problems and ended up putting together a library to extend the in-memory provider to support relational operations - [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing). It'll do the ExecuteSqlCommand/ExecuteSqlCommandAsync mocking.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively in this scenario, you can use SQLite as an in-memory database when running the test suite to avoid network usage, it supports many SQL features but  has some limitations.

```
services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(connection)
            );
```